# cron to merge xml into sqlite every two hours - lamp

Tags: mysql, cron, lamp, xml, sqlite

I'm looking to auto pull an xml file from an offsite url and merge it into a sqlite db every two hours. The server is lamp. (If it is too difficult to do for sqlite, then merging the xml into a mysql table would also be fine.)

**xml:**

```
<entries>
  <entry>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = $argv[1];
if(!$file)
    exit(1);

$data = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach ($data as $entry){
    foreach($entry as $k=>$v){
       // change this to insert into the db ...
       echo $k . "=" . $v . "\n";
    }
}

# cron job php -q /script.php file.xml
```